# iOS - Know when modal view has been dismissed

Tags: iphone, ios, uinavigationcontroller, modalviewcontroller

I have a UIViewController which I present a modalViewController in.  After the modal view is shown, the user can dismiss it.

**Is there a way to know when that modal view has been completely dismissed so I can fire a method from the original controller?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like a job for: viewDidDisappear: from http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: This is wrong. viewDidDisappear can be called by the camera when taking a photo and it will restore your view after photo.